# Query where values contain values from another sheet

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I need to query a sheet in another sheet and return and filter a list by matches containing. Heres my sheet:

Sheet2:

[image: 0]

Sheet1:

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FILTER` instead like:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:B, REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!A:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D)))
```

[image: 0]